# how to open multiple lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox2

I have a gallery on a page. When you click one of the thumbnail the gallery will appear for the corresponding album. Within the album, when you click on the image a bigger and clearer version of the picture clicked on will appear in a lightbox. [the gallery is on this site](http://lfupholstery.net/home.html) Im just wondering how can I open two lightbox instead of one. It could be one stack on top of the other or beneath I just need to open two.  Below is the code that Im using now it only open one lightbox when you click on a picture.

```
<a href="images/headboards/lhb1.jpg" class="triggerLightbox"><img src="images/headboards/hb1.jpg" alt="Headboard" width="620" height="350" /></a>
```

Comment: what lightbox plugin do you use?

Comment: FancyBox - jQuery Plugin

Answer (score 0):

create two or more link image with same value of attribute `rel` like this:

```
<a rel="group" href="images/headboards/lhb1.jpg" class="triggerLightbox"><img src="images/headboards/hb1.jpg" alt="Headboard" width="620" height="350" /></a>
<a rel="group" href="images/headboards/lhb2.jpg" class="triggerLightbox"><img src="images/headboards/hb2.jpg" alt="Headboard" width="620" height="350" /></a>
```

good luck!

Comment: You are along the right track but this creates two links in the album. The reason I need the code is because in the album there are images that have have two product in one picture. So I need it to work so that when you click on the image two light boxes come out showing the two product in separate lightboxes.